# Sharepoint 2010 unextend web application

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to unextend a web application.

First i tried this code:

```
getWebApp.IisSettings.Remove(SPUrlZone.Internet);
```

It is working fine but not deleting the IIS website or physical folder of this extended web app. So i started to delete IIS website manually by using the following code:

```
int instID = getWebApp.IisSettings[SPUrlZone.Internet].PreferredInstanceId;
SPIisWebSite iisWebSite = new SPIisWebSite(instID);
iisWebSite.Unprovision();
```

or:

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
Site s1 = iisManager.Sites["MySiteName - 1234"]; // you can pass the site name or the site ID
iisManager.Sites.Remove(s1);
iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

IIS website is not getting deleted.

Any help?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post: http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2008/04/un-extend-web-application/

Comment: Tuncy thanks for your help.                                        But i already went through this link and they using some third party API for getting this method Utilities.ExecuteMethod().

Comment: i got my answer my from some other source and not from here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without code.  In SharePoint 2010, all you need to do is go to Central Administration, Manage Web Application, select your application, select the drop down below the 'Delete' button and select 'Remove SharePoint from IIS web site'.  Select your extended site, then also be sure to select 'Yes' to delete the site from IIS.

Comment: I wanted it programmatically.

I have got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SPWebApplication getWebApp = GetWebAppById(GlobalVar._webAppId);

 getWebApp.IisSettings.Remove(SPUrlZone.Internet);
 getWebApp.Update();
 Directory.Delete(GlobalVar._exWebAppPhyPath, true);
 ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
 Site getSite = iisManager.Sites[GlobalVar._webAppExtendedName];
 iisManager.Sites.Remove(getSite);
 iisManager.CommitChanges();
 getWebApp.Update();
 getWebApp.Provision();
```